# Should a library used by getStaticProps be a normal or dev dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using a library in NextJS's `getStaticProps`. As such the library will only be used as build time.
Should this dependence be a normal or dev `dependency` in my `package.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you have it in this case where you are building a website. Making the difference between `devDependencies` and `dependencies` is important if you are creating a library that other developers will install with `npm i packageName`.

As an example if you install `axios` you install along everything in its `dependencies`. And those get registered in your `package-lock.json` but not its `devDependencies`, as you don't need them, as they are only for `axios`'s creators to develop it and test it.

Here are is a quote about `devDependencies` from `npm`'s official [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#devdependencies):

> If someone is planning on downloading and using your module in their program, then they probably don't want or need to download and build the external test or documentation framework that you use.

Comment: Does dependencies vs devDependencies never affect the final bundle? I know there's also other factors eg tree shaking, but I assumed they weren't 100% equivalent?

Comment: Non it won’t affect the final bundle. You get in the final bundle only what you import with `import`. And tree shaking makes sure to remove from the bundle imports that are not used and does others optimizations.

Comment: And I think Next.js is smart enough to not send to the browser what’s only used by `getStaticProps`.